# AutocompleteExtender from a 65000 record in sql table

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to Autocomplete City names from a huge sql table. My code below work but its very slow and sometimes it freezes because I got a lot repeated suggestions. any way to filter all this repeated string to make it faster ? thanks

```
Public Function GetCompletionList(ByVal prefixText As String, ByVal count As Integer) As String()

    Dim strCn As String = "Data Source=sqlserver\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=zip;User ID=sa;Password=xxx"
    cn.ConnectionString = strCn
    Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    cmd.Connection = cn
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from zip_code Where City like @myParameter+'%'"
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myParameter", prefixText)

    Try
        cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim dt As New DataTable()

        da.Fill(ds)
    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
        cn.Close()
    End Try

    dt = ds.Tables(0)

            Dim txtItems As New List(Of String)()
    Dim dbValues As String

    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
          dbValues = row("City").ToString()
        dbValues = dbValues.ToLower()
        txtItems.Add(dbValues)
    Next

    Return txtItems.ToArray
```

Comment: Try replacing `select *` with `select distinct City` to start.

Comment: 65,000 is nothing. I hope you execute this on a non-Dispatcher thread ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are executing your SQL twice, once during ExecuteNonQuery, second time during Fill.
2. You are not using IDisposable objects correctly.
3. You return all columns.
4. If you have a control for display, check if it will accept Rows (Dataset?) property directly. Don't copy.

**UPDATE**

Your connection, command and other objects implement an IDisposable interface. So they should be placed in a using block:

```
Using { resourcelist | resourceexpression }
    [ statements ]
End Using
```

Then you don't have to worry about closing and disposing a database connection.

**UPDATE 2**

Your code has thread safety issues, the same connection must not be shared by two different threads. EVER. Two consecutive Fill request and one will close the database connection before the other can finish.

Comment: thanks, it's a lot faster when I rearrange my code to run the query just once and use select distinct. can you please elaborate on Idisposable. like I said I'm using ajax Autocomplete extender to get the results.

Comment: Using is preferred, but if the Close() call is in a Finally block, it's okay, and certainly doesn't rise to the level of "incorrect".

Comment: Also: Fill() manages connections. The docs state that it will both open and close a connection as needed. But yes, it's very bad to share a connection object in a web app.

Comment: I guess, The Purist got the better of me. And people battled this subject elsewhere. Thanks @JoelCoehoorn.

Comment: That's a good comment on Fill. Caught me by surprise then first time I've learned about it. @JoelCoehoorn.